# Internal Server Error when installing opencart

Tags: php, opencart, internal-server-error

I'm new to open cart , I jsut uploaded the files to the server and trying to install it but invaine , it gives me 500 internal server error , and it seems to be from the .htacess file

it had been .htacess.txt , I renamed to .htacess and  removed the comments from the commands it 's said to remove to git rid of this error but it still the same ! 
how to fix this ?

and here is the online files http://idev-inc.com/projects/idev_market.com/

```
  # 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

 # 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

 # For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

 #Options +FollowSymlinks

  # Prevent Directoy listing 
 Options -Indexes

 # Prevent Direct Access to files
 <FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
  Order deny,allow

 </FilesMatch>

  # SEO URL Settings
 RewriteEngine On
 # If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you           folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
 RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
 RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
 RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

 ### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
 ### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
 ### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following      settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

 # 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible           register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
  php_flag register_globals off

 # 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

 # 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be      overridden but you can try
   php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

 # 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or      are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
   php_value post_max_size 999M

 # 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product      options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
   php_value max_execution_time 200

 # 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of      product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
```

php_value max_input_time 200

```
 # 7. disable open_basedir limitations
   php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Comment: Comment out all of the commands towards the bottom starting `php_flag` and `php_value`

Comment: Look into the server’s error log …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing the php.ini file , it may conflict the server config , remove it and it will be intialized auto again !

Answer (score 1):

On certain web hosting servers many of the Apache's settings are not editable with `.htaccess` files. In such cases the settings in Your `.htaccess` interfering with this prohibition will cause a `500 internal server error`.

On my hosting I had to comment out (remove) everything except `RewriteEngine` settings and `Options +FollowSymlinks`. Each other setting (even `Options -Indexes`) was causing me `500 error`.

There should be some *administrator's manual* provided by Your web hosting provider (try to search their knowledge base or ask them directly) about which settings are allowed in `.htaccess` files.

Comment: I have sent them a ticket and waiting for there replay , thanks alot for your replay